# how to represent 5 billion in java and sequential integer values

Tags: java

I am wondering how to represent 5400000000,5400000001,5400000002,.... in java
(how to represent 5 billion in java)

java ints only hold 2^32-1,
java longs hold 2^64-1,..but i am having a problem representing  5400000000,5400000001,5400000002,....and doubles aren't helping either.

can someone plz provide insight how to represent large values like this (IN JAVA) without having to do multiplication on strings
because Long max = Long(5462205000); just isnt doing it for me.
thx in advance

Comment: Surely `5400000000` can be represented by a `long`? In any case, such a sequence is likely better encoded as a "Range" type, which has a *start* and a *count* (or *end*). I do not know of any such standard type in Java, however.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your 64-bit integer type can easily hold numbers like 5 billion. Even the signed version can hold values up to `9223372036854775807`. Slow bigint libraries not necessary.

To specify these in code you need to use what's called a 'long int literal', which means adding an `L` to the end of the number. Example:

```
long x = 5000000000L;
```

Comment: Ah yes, I was wondering what the L was for. I ended up going with BigInteger tho. Thanks.

Comment: Whenever I /have/ to create an indefinite loop, I instead opt to loop until the sun burns out in the year 2-billion. `while (System.currentTimeMillis() < 7773669572582567141l) { ... }`

Answer (score 4):

Put an L at the end, e.g.

```
5400000001L
          ^
```

so the compiler knows it's a long

Answer (score 2):

You're having a syntax issue.  This will fix your issue nicely:

```
Long max = new Long(5462205000L);
```

You need to add the `L` suffix to indicate this as a Long, otherwise the Java compiler is assuming you're entering an Integer, and this # (anything beyond 2,147,483,647) falls beyond the range of an Integer.